# Change ng-repeat end of the screen to other side of the screen

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a ng-repeat in a div with some data. What i basically want is output the data to the left side of the screen. When it is reached, it moves on to the right side of the screen. The height of the screen is the result of how long the ng-repeat is.
Could somebody help me with this?

```
  left side of   right side of
   the screen     the screen
 _____________________________
|  ng-repeat    |    data11   |
|    data1      |      .      |
|      .        |      .      |
|      .        |      .      |
|      .        |      .      |
|      .        |      .      |
|      .        |      .      |
|      .        |      .      |
|      .        |      .      |
|      .        |      .      |
|      .        |      .      |
|      .        |      .      |
|    data10     |    data20   |
|_______________|_____________|
```

Comment: means say in first column data1 - data10, second column data11- data20, after that rest comes in thired column i.e data21- data30, etc... am i right

Comment: @NidhishKrishnan yea almost. its more like, if there are data 1 - data 6 then the left side will be data1- data3 and right side will be data4 - data6. so the height of that panel will depend on the number of data in that array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say if you have 20 data's, from the Array you could get the length by using the function `.length`, so 10 in left hand side and 10 in right hand side, In `Angular JS` while populating values through `ng-repeat`, you can fill the first half within the **left hand side** by using [limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) like as shown below

`ng-repeat="val in values|limitTo:ceil(values.length/2)"`

Here ceil is used in such a way that say if you have 23 datas, then you could not get perfect half, in such a way that either left or right should accumulate one extra number, i.e 12 in left and 11 in right

[image]

**[`limitTo`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)** is filter in Angular JS for limiting the numbers in ng-repeat, The syntax is given below

```
{{ limitTo_expression | limitTo : limit}}
```

Also you want to use `ceil` function within limitTo you have to inject `Math` into your `scope`,

Simplest way, you can do

```
 $scope.ceil = Math.ceil;
```

In your controller. `Angular` way to do this correctly would be create a `Math` service

Similarly in the **right hand side** you can fill by using

```
ng-repeat="val in values|limitTo:-values.length/2"
```

Take a look at this example

**html**

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JMUJ4/)**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="ArrayController">
    <div class="left">
        <span ng-repeat="val in values|limitTo:ceil(values.length/2)">{{val}}
            <br/>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <span ng-repeat="val in values|limitTo:-values.length/2">{{val}}
            <br/>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
angular.module("app", [])
.controller('ArrayController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.ceil = Math.ceil;
    $scope.values = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4',
        'data5', 'data6', 'data7', 'data8',
        'data9', 'data10', 'data11', 'data12',
        'data13', 'data14', 'data15', 'data16',
        'data17', 'data18', 'data19', 'data20'];
});
```

Comment: Yes, thank you sir! I've implemented into my code and it worked perfect =]!

Comment: Like I said before, Thanks for the answer sir. But i got a new problem with this. If I want to push new data to the array, it won't show the correct data. Sometimes it will push it to the array but it wont update in the view.. Do you know how to fix this problem?

Comment: for that create a new SO question since its a new requirement

Answer (score 1):

Simply repeat only the first half of the data in the first column, and the rest in the second column. The [`limitTo`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) filter will help you. Notice that its second argument can be a negative number.

Besides, since [`limitTo` truncates the number](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/aa268560064e5875bd471da3f7d1ebc2f9e6b3b7/src/ng/filter/limitTo.js#L79) being passed, you'll want to [`ceil`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) it if you're likely to have an odd number of items.

```js
$scope.ceil = Math.ceil;
```

```html
<ul id="myFirstColumn">
     <li ng-repeat="data in dataList | limitTo:ceil(dataList.length / 2)"></li>
</ul>
<ul id="mySecondColumn">
     <li ng-repeat="data in dataList | limitTo:-dataList.length / 2"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes thank you, i saw the code of NidhishKrishsnan, but they are basically the same, so thank you!

Comment: They are exactly the same, but his is more detailed. I'm glad you've solved your problem!